# Adicionar <option> ao <select> com jQuery através do callback do $.post

Tags: jquery, json, loop

Estou a fazer um `select` que terá alguns usuários e ao selecionar um usuário irá mandar uma requisição `$.post` para pegar todos cadastros relacionados ao usuário selecionado. Após retornar os cadastros relacionados, o **jQuery** irá retornar o `callback` do `$.post` e através dos dados retornados eu preciso fazer um loop para adicionar todos os nomes retornados dentro do `<option></option>`, o problema é que não sei como fazer isso. Os dados será retornado em **jSON** pelo PHP e o jQuery tem que capturar pelo callback e formar um loop para colocar no `<option>`.

Eu sei que para adicionar um registro ao `option` eu uso o código

```
$('#example').append('<option value="foo" selected="selected">Foo</option>');
```

Mas queria saber como faço um loop com o jSON retornado pelo callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando o resultado do Ajax é um JSON, o jQuery automaticamente o converte em um objeto JavaScript comum. Dessa forma, tudo o que você tem que fazer é acessar suas propriedades (ou índices, se for um array) normalmente. Por exemplo, se seu resultado for assim (quebras de linha acrescentadas por legibilidade):

```
{ "resultados":{
    "lista":[
        {"valor":"foo", "texto":"Foo"}, {"valor":"bar", "texto":"Bar"},
        {"valor":"baz", "texto":"Baz"}
    ],
    "etc":"etc" 
  },
  "etc":"etc"
}
```

Seu código seria:

```
$.post(url, argumentos, function(json) {
    var lista = json.resultados.lista;
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < lista.length ; i++ ) {
        var option = $("<option></option>").appendTo($('#example'));
        option.attr("value", lista[i].valor);
        option.html(lista[i].texto);

        // ou (mais feio):
        $('#example').append('<option value="' + lista[i].valor + '">' +
                             lista[i].texto + '</option>');
    }
}, 'json');
```

Ou se o seu resultado fosse algo do tipo:

```
{ "foo":"Foo", "bar","Bar", "baz":"Baz" }
```

Seu código poderia ser assim:

```
$.post(url, argumentos, function(json) {
    for ( var valor in json ) if( json.hasOwnProperty(valor) ) {
        var option = $("<option></option>").appendTo($('#example'));
        option.attr("value", valor);
        option.html(json[valor]);
    }
}, 'json');
```

Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que sua estrutura de retorno como:

```
usuarios = [
    {"id" : 1, "login": "joao"},
    {"id" : 2, "login": "maria"}
];
```

[Segundo a própia documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) ([o segredo está aqui, na função each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)):

```
$.post("http://urlQueRetornaArrayEmFormatoJSON", function(retorno) {
    $.each(retorno, function(indice, usuario){  
        $("#seuSelect").append(new Option(usuario.login, usuario.id));
    });
});
```

ou da própia forma como você já disse saber fazer:

```
$.post("http://urlQueRetornaArrayEmFormatoJSON", function(retorno) {
    $.each(retorno, function(indice, usuario){  
        $('#seuSelect').append('<option value="' + usuario.id + '" slected="selected">' + usuario.login + '</option>');
    });
});
```

- [Exemplo funcional Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/2196/)